# XmlSerializer Convert C# object to xml string issue

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following code but i not want to show the node called "booksList".
i need your help about the solution i delete the XmlArrayItem tag but not work properly.

**i took the example from the following post**:

*You cannot serialize class from your question using standard serialization tools so that it will have  entries on the same level as  node.
When class saved with standard serialization tools list of your  nodes will always be nested into separate array node that will be on the same level as  node. Same concerns records array field on book class.
To generate XML output that you want to - with  nodes on same level as  node - you will have to implement IXmlSerializable interface in your books class for custom serialization. To see examples of IXmlSerializable implementation visit these links: StackOverflow answer, CodeProject article.
Another solution will be - as stated user Alexandr in comment to my answer - to inherit your books class from List type and to have on your book class field records of class type that is inherited from List type.*

```
[XmlRoot("books")]
public class books
{
    [XmlElement("bookNum")]
    public int bookNum { get; set; }

    [XmlRoot("book")]
    public class book
    {
        [XmlElement("name")]
        public string name { get; set; }

        [XmlRoot("record")]
        public class record
        {
            [XmlElement("borrowDate")]
            public string borrowDate { get; set; }

            [XmlElement("returnDate")]
            public string returnDate { get; set; }
        }

        [XmlArray("borrowRecords")]
        [XmlArrayItem("record")]
        public record[] records { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlArray("booksList")]
    [XmlArrayItem("book")]
    public book[] books { get; set; }
}
```

```
<books>
    <bookNum>2</bookNum>
    <booksList>
        <book>
            <name>Book 1</name>
            <borrowRecords>
                <record>
                    <borrowDate>2013-1-3</borrowDate>
                    <returnDate>2013-1-5</returnDate>
                </record>
                <record>            
                    <borrowDate>2013-2-3</borrowDate>
                    <returnDate>2013-4-5</returnDate>
                </record>
            </borrowRecords>
        </book>
        <book>
            <name>Book 2</name>
            <borrowRecords>
                <record>
                    <borrowDate>2013-1-3</borrowDate>
                    <returnDate>2013-1-5</returnDate>
                </record>
                <record>            
                    <borrowDate>2013-2-3</borrowDate>
                    <returnDate>2013-4-5</returnDate>
                </record>
            </borrowRecords>
        </book>
    </booksList>
</books>
```

if i use the tag "XmlIgnore" like Ed Plunkett says work but i delete all the data inside the array, i want the data but not the "booksList" node.

like this:

```
<books>
    <bookNum>2</bookNum>
    <book>
        <name>Book 1</name>
        <borrowRecords>
            <record>
                <borrowDate>2013-1-3</borrowDate>
                <returnDate>2013-1-5</returnDate>
            </record>
            <record>
                <borrowDate>2013-2-3</borrowDate>
                <returnDate>2013-4-5</returnDate>
            </record>
        </borrowRecords>
    </book>
    <book>
        <name>Book 2</name>
        <borrowRecords>
            <record>
                <borrowDate>2013-1-3</borrowDate>
                <returnDate>2013-1-5</returnDate>
            </record>
            <record>
                <borrowDate>2013-2-3</borrowDate>
                <returnDate>2013-4-5</returnDate>
            </record>
        </borrowRecords>
    </book>
</books>
```

i use this example because the original data i can't show, but is the same problem i need to delete the "booksList" because is the standar i need to use.

Comment: If the root node isn't there, it's won't be valid XML. Why do you believe there is a problem with the XML as it is?

Comment: because the requirements is without the node "booksList"

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. There's nothing in your question about `booksList` and requirements. You wrote *"i not want to show the node called "books""*, which is the root node. Was that a typo?

Comment: sorry i wrote wrong the question

Comment: Thank you. If you want the serialization to ignore `booksList`, use the [XmlIgnore attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributes.xmlignore?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Thanks again for the update. Why do you want to do this? It's not a good idea. You'll have to do something exotic to deserialize the XML again. Are you producing XML for some consumer which is out of your control and requires this format? In that case I'm afraid your best bet may be manually writing the serialization code.

Comment: yes is for a consumer and want the xml like i sais without that node, like you said i think i need to re-think the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution, just change or add the [XmlArrayItem("book")] for [XmlElement("book")] in the cs class like this:

```
[XmlRoot("books")]
public class books
{
    [XmlElement("bookNum")]
    public int bookNum { get; set; }

    [XmlRoot("book")]
    public class book
    {
        [XmlElement("name")]
        public string name { get; set; }

        [XmlRoot("record")]
        public class record
        {
            [XmlElement("borrowDate")]
            public string borrowDate { get; set; }

            [XmlElement("returnDate")]
            public string returnDate { get; set; }
        }

        [XmlElement("record")]
        public record[] records { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlElement("book")]
    public book[] books { get; set; }
}
```

and this gets the following xml file:

```
<books>
    <bookNum>2</bookNum>
    <book>
        <name>Book 1</name>
        <borrowRecords>
            <record>
                <borrowDate>2013-1-3</borrowDate>
                <returnDate>2013-1-5</returnDate>
            </record>
            <record>
                <borrowDate>2013-2-3</borrowDate>
                <returnDate>2013-4-5</returnDate>
            </record>
        </borrowRecords>
    </book>
    <book>
        <name>Book 2</name>
        <borrowRecords>
            <record>
                <borrowDate>2013-1-3</borrowDate>
                <returnDate>2013-1-5</returnDate>
            </record>
            <record>
                <borrowDate>2013-2-3</borrowDate>
                <returnDate>2013-4-5</returnDate>
            </record>
        </borrowRecords>
    </book>
</books>
```

without the node ""